# Using a BackgroundWorker to call a serialization method

Tags: c#, multithreading, serialization, backgroundworker

I've run into a problem that I can't figure out how to solve, so I'm starting to think that I'm not understanding the BackgroundWorker correctly.

I'm trying to use a BackgroundWorker to handle the saving/loading functionality in my program, which means that I want the worker to call the serialization methods that I've created.

The serialization method takes a POCO and xml serializes it. This POCO contains multiple properties and one of these is of type Brush.

```
public Brush ShapeColor{ get; set; }
```

I want to serialize the Color but as I can't serialize a Brush, I've made an assisting property:

```
public Color StoreColor
{
    get
    {          
         g = ((Color)ShapeColor.GetValue(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty)).G;
         r = ((Color)ShapeColor.GetValue(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty)).R;
         b = ((Color)ShapeColor.GetValue(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty)).B;           
         return Color.FromRgb(r, g, b);
    }
    set {}
}
```

This works fine without the use of a `BackgroundWorker`. 
But as soon as I try to make the method call to the serialization method in the `doWork` method, an exception is cast:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

On these:

```
g = ((Color)ShapeColor.GetValue(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty)).G;
r = ((Color)ShapeColor.GetValue(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty)).R;
b = ((Color)ShapeColor.GetValue(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty)).B;
```

My understanding is that by using a `BackgroundWorker` to call the serialization method from another thread than the UI thread, I violate the rule stating that a worker cannot access UI elements.

To be honest I'm not quite sure how to formulate my question, but is it not possible for me to just serialize these POCO's from a worker? Has it something to do with the `ShapeColor` being a brush?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad explanation :)

EDIT: Posting the xml serialization method.

```
public static void convertToXML<T>(T objectToSave, string path) where T : new()
    {
        StreamWriter streamWriter = null;
        try
        {               
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path, false);             

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
            {
                Indent = true,
                OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
            };
            serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, objectToSave);

        }
        finally
        {
            // Close writer
            if (streamWriter != null)
            {
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to check ```Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId``` when you creating ```ShapeColor``` and when accessing it here.

Comment: GDI objects like brushes aren't just data structures, they are tied to the UI thread. You *can't* and *don't need to* use a BGW for this. BGW is deprecated and completely unnecessary for asynchronous saving. You can use the asynchronous methods of eg FileStream to save data asynchronously

Comment: Please post your *serialization* code. The code you posted doesn't cause the problem, nor can it be modified to fix it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So yeah, I read some and found that it sounds like you have the answer for me :) - I would be able to modify the serialization code to implement async calls as the StreamWriter API support the async methods?

And then just scrap the whole BGW idea :)? So each time I serialize something, the serialization method takes care of handling the task in another thread?

Comment: It is a pretty specific WPF restriction.  Kinda heavy-handed but it takes a no-nonsense attitude to thread-safety on extension properties.  Nothing much you can do about it, you'll need to prep the data on the UI thread before you let the worker thread save it.  Won't make the code any prettier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've run into `Freezable` objects.

These objects can only typically be handled in an `Unfrozen` state from the thread that created them (which in your case is the `Dispatcher` thread).

In order to handle them (and not manipulate them) on another thread, you either need to `Freeze()` them and then hand them over to the other thread OR make the call on the `Dispatcher` thread using `Dispatcher.Invoke()`.

```
int r =0;
int g =0;
int b =0;
//Marshalls back to UI thread
Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{
 r = ((Color)ShapeColor.GetValue(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty)).R;
 g = ((Color)ShapeColor.GetValue(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty)).G;
 b = ((Color)ShapeColor.GetValue(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty)).B;
});
//Creates object on BGW thread and can be safely used for serialization
return Color.FromRgb(r, g, b);
```

Comment: So I tried your solution at it works :)! Although I have to use 'Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke ..' instead.

I don't know if that is alright to do though?

Comment: It is okay to do as generally there is only one Dispatcher per Application. You can have multiple Dispatchers, but it's quite a specialised, advanced thing to do. Please remember to mark as the answer. :)